Como usar laravel-filemanager con tinymce 7
Tengo mi editor de publicaciones que usaba tinymce 4 y recientemente lo actualicé a la última versión, pero al momento que quiero utilizar mi manejador de archivos, sí abre, pero al seleccionar mi imagen la abre en una nueva pestaña y no lo coloca en mi editor.
En cuanto al código, según lo que vi en la migración, se hace de la siguiente forma:
...
file_picker_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
    var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName(
        'body')[0].clientWidth;
    var y = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document
        .getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

    var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + '/laravel-filemanager?editor=tinymce5';
    if (type == 'image') {
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
    } else {
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
    }
    console.log(cmsURL);
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.openUrl({
        url: cmsURL,
        title: 'Filemanager',
        width: x * 0.8,
        height: y * 0.8,
        close_previous: "no",
        onMessage: (api, message) => {
            callback(message.content);
        }
    });
}

Se logra abrir y se mostraban los archivos, pero al momento de seleccionar un archivo, este se abre en una nueva pestaña, pero no se agrega en mi editor. En este caso, ¿Estoy saltándome un paso o se necesita agregar algo para compatibilizarlo?
